# Form submission through Ajax by inserting multiple selections into one row separated by comma in DB but implode giving error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a Ajax form that is submitting data into my MySQL database.

I have select2 boxes that allow users to select multiple choices.

Here is an example of one box's **HTLM** code:

```
<select class="select3 form-control select2-multiple track" name="sellingmethods" id ="sellingmethods" multiple="multiple" multiple data-placeholder="Choose ...">
    <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
    <option value="Party Planning">Party Planning</option>
    <option value="Door to Door">Door to Door</option>
    <option value="Face to Face">Face to Face</option>
    <option value="Online Demos">Online Demos</option>
    <option value="Affiliate Link">Affiliate Link</option>
    <option value="Appointment Setting">Appointment Setting</option>
</select>
```

When I click submit it passes the data like this :

[image: Example Ajax Post Data]

As you can see it posts the same id of the box multiple times example seen on selling methods.

At the moment my PHP code that puts it in the DB is only putting the last item into the database.

Is there a way to put the multiple selections in separated by a comma? For example "door to door,telesales".

Here is my current PHP code :

```
'sellingmethods' => implode(',', $this->input->post('sellingmethods')),
'sellertype' => implode(',', $this->input->post('sellertype')),
'want2sell' => implode(',', $this->input->post('want2sell')),
'productssold' => implode(',', $this->input->post('productssold')),
'industriesrepresented' => implode(',', $this->input->post('industriesrepresented')),
```

Which is currently giving me the error :

`implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the multiple options submitted through a select multiple as an array, you will need to set the name attribute as an array eg `sellingmethods[]`

So for example:

```
<select class="select3 form-control select2-multiple track" name="sellingmethods[]" id ="sellingmethods" multiple="multiple" multiple data-placeholder="Choose ...">

 <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
 <option value="Party Planning">Party Planning</option>
 <option value="Door to Door">Door to Door</option>
 <option value="Face to Face">Face to Face</option>
 <option value="Online Demos">Online Demos</option>
 <option value="Affiliate Link">Affiliate Link</option>
 <option value="Appointment Setting">Appointment Setting</option>
</select>
```

Then `$this->input->post('sellingmethods')` or `$_POST['sellingmethods']` will be an array as expected, and you should no longer get the error for your implode() function.